# Bootstrap NavBar with right aligned items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to align my navbar to the right in bootstrap 4.3.1.
I want to have the navbar-brand on the right and navbar-item on the leftBut everything I try does not seem to work.

[this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKpVS.png) how it look right now i want to be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BohK.png)

**This is my code:**

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
    <img src="image/logo.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" style="filter: invert(1)" alt="">
    my new website
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
     <?php $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
     <li class="nav-item <?= $uri == '/test.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
      <a class="nav-link" href="test.php">test</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item <?= $uri == '/test.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>">
      <a class="nav-link" href="tset.php">test</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">other</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item <?= $uri == '/test.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>" href="test.php">test</a>
       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
       <a class="dropdown-item <?= $uri == '/test.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>" href="stat.php">test</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0" style="flex-direction: row;">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="padding-right: .5rem;padding-left: .5rem;" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
       <img src="images/facebook.svg" width="24" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-top" style="filter: invert(1)" alt="">
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="padding-right: .5rem;padding-left: .5rem;" href="https://github.com" target="_blank">
       <img src="images/github.svg" width="24" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-top" style="filter: invert(1)" alt="">
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `d-flex flex-row-reverse` to the nav's class. After that, you should try to change the order if there is something wrong (I think the images won't be in the right order). Also, I think you should put the `.container` div to the outside of your nav or even the whole page. 
[Here's the bootstrap 4.4 doc about flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)